# How to create a pie chart of user points and taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users, userpoints, charts

I have 3 terms in `Taxonomy > User Points`: *Articles*, *Comments* and *Favorites*. I created some rules to grant user points of one of these categories, based upon the users' actions. So far, everything works fine.

Now, I'd like to create a pie chart of the user points per category for the profile pages. For example, such a pie chart might look like this:

[image: Pie chart]

How can I achieve this?

---

**Edit:** I'm working with User Points 7.x-1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of [chart modules](https://groups.drupal.org/node/93064) for drupal.

If you used the [charts module](https://drupal.org/project/charts), it has views integration, so assuming you are using the user points module, and that user points has view integration, you should be able to create a view with items grouped by term and display as a chart.

### *Update*

Replicated your environment as above, updated the userpoints module to 7.x-1.x (dev), installed charts module (and included google charts module to test), constructed view of userpoints with contextual filter on user and the chart  works perfectly! Thanks for asking the question, I have suddenly thought of loads of places I could use similar graphic incentives.

Here is the exported view - in this example it uses taxonomy terms article, page and comments:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'points_chart_userpoints';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'userpoints';
$view->human_name = 'points_chart_userpoints';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'userpoints table block';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'chart';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['library'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['label_field'] = 'tid';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['data_fields'] = array(
  'points' => 'points',
  'tid' => 'tid',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['field_colors'] = array(
  'points' => '#2f7ed8',
  'tid' => '#0d233a',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['width'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['height'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['xaxis_labels_rotation'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['yaxis_labels_rotation'] = '0';
/* No results behavior: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['label'] = 'no points';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['empty'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = 'no points found';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['format'] = 'filtered_html';
/* Relationship: Userpoints: User */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'userpoints';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Field: Userpoints: Current points in category */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['id'] = 'points';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['table'] = 'userpoints';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['field'] = 'points';
/* Field: Userpoints: Points category */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['tid']['id'] = 'tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['tid']['table'] = 'userpoints';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['tid']['field'] = 'tid';
/* Contextual filter: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_options']['user'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

/* Display: Chart (block) */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Chart (block)', 'block');

/* Display: Table (block) */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Table (block)', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'points' => 'points',
  'tid' => 'tid',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'points' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'tid' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'userpoints/chart';
```

Comment: I've installed the Charts module and created a pie chart. I'm getting the following errors: **1)** `Strict warning: Declaration of userpoints_views_handler_field_category::init() should be compatible with views_handler::init(&$view, &$options) in _registry_check_code() (line 3160 of C:\wamp\www\mysite\includes\bootstrap.inc).`
**2)** `Strict warning: Declaration of userpoints_views_handler_field_category::pre_render() should be compatible with views_handler_field::pre_render(&$values) in _registry_check_code() (line 3160 of C:\wamp\www\mysite\includes\bootstrap.inc).` Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: I have not used userpoints module specifically, but itr sounds like this is very much a problem with userpoints code rather than misconfiguration. I would try updating userpoints to the dev version to see if they have fixed this. Other than that I have no suggestions except perhaps flushing the views cache just in case.

Comment: If (or while) you continue to have problems with userpoints>views>charts, the only solution (hack) I can suggest is to duplicate the user points in another field with better integration with views. As a last resort, or temporarily, you could use views_php or computed_field to get your userpoints values into a different field in the view.

Comment: replicated your setup and had same warning, updated userpoints to 7.x-1.x and it went away

Comment: That's odd: I'm working with User Points 7.x-1.0 too. Did you activate the Userpoints Service? I didn't.

Comment: I did not activate userpoints service for test. To be clear, I installed the dev version (7.x-1.0+10-dev) rather than the (green) recommended release (http://goo.gl/gZzrIS). I used userpoints_nc to award the points.

Comment: Thanks for your update! My pie chart looks exactly the same. As I don't like to use a dev-version of a module on my website (I'm not sure whether it's stable), I now know that I'll have to find a solution by looking for some kind of patch. Thanks again for the great tip of using the Charts module!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I understand your point regarding dev/production versions, but would a patch not also introduce some uncertainty?

Comment: Perhaps, but I think it's a safer way when the patch has been tested before. Anyway, the chart works perfectly, it's just those error messages who're bothering me. I'll just have to live with them until I find a solution...